# Creating an Object that an only have certain int values

Tags: c#, object, enums, model

I have an enum `Days` that looks like this:

```
public enum Days
    {
        Sunday = 1,
        Monday = 2,
        Tuesday = 3,
        Wednesday = 4,
        Thursday = 5,
        Friday = 6,
        Saturday = 7,
    }
```

and I want to have a similar enum/object for `Hours` that forcing the value to be an `int` between `0` and `23`, i.e. to look something like:

```
public enum Hours
    {
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
    }
```

where it only has an int value and no identifier with it. Now I know enums don't work like this so I can't use an enum, but is there another way I can accomplish having an object like this?

Comment: Have you considered using DateTime?

Comment: A cheap solution, you can use an enum and use a prefix like "D" (for days), per example D0 = 0, D1 = 1, and so on. But beware, you can assign ANY integer value to an enum, so you can perfectly do `Days d = (Days)1555;`

Comment: I would start using DateTime object, to deal with that kind of data.

Comment: I am using DateTime objects, which is how I get that data, but then I am passing lists of "hours" and "days" to repos and other places around my project so it is easier to handle if they have their own objects

Comment: how about creating a static class and adding int props or int variables. reliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums don't actually force the value to be one of the given values. For example, even if you had an Enum like this:

```
public enum Numbers
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

The following would still be considered legal syntax:

```
Numbers n = (Numbers)3;
```

Instead, what you should do is create a property for your `Hours` field and validate the input so that it will throw an exception if the given value isn't within the allowed range:

```
private int _hours;
public int Hours
{
    get { return _hours; }
    set 
    {
        if (value < 0 || value > 23)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Hours), "The value must be between 0 and 23");
        _hours = value;
    }
}
```

That being said, what you are working with is a day and an hour (and presumably minutes or seconds or months), so a `DateTime` object already has all the functionality you would need.

```
private DateTime _dt;

public int Days
{
    get { return _dt.Day; }
    set { _dt = new DateTime(_dt.Year, _dt.Month, value, _dt.Hour, _dt.Minute, _dt.Second, _dt.Millisecond); }
}

public int Hours
{
    get { return _dt.Hour; }
    set { _dt = new DateTime(_dt.Year, _dt.Month, _dt.Day, value, _dt.Minute, _dt.Second, _dt.Millisecond); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use datetime, then probably your next best thing is to use a struct with some implicit conversions

```
public struct Hour
{
    private int val;

    public Hour(int val)
    {
        validate(val);
        this.val = val;
    }

    private static void validate(int hour)
    {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            throw new Exception("it broke");
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Hour h)
    {
        return h.val;
    }

    public static implicit operator Hour(int d)
    {
        return new Hour(d);
    }
}
```

The implicit operators allow you to treat the object like an int most of the time and the validate function ensures that you always have a valid value.

So you should be able to do stuff like `Hour h = 23;` and `int time = h;` but not `Hour h = 30;`

Answer (score 1):

I would check it in the setter:

```
private int hour;
public int Hour
{
    get { return hour; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0 || value > 23)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        hour = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make either an enum with the word for each number or an array with length 24 where the value at each index is equal to the index.

Ex:

```
enum
{
   Zero = 0,
   One,
   Two
}

var days = int[24] { 0, 1, 2, ..., 22, 23 };
days[0]; // == 0
```

Comment: I want to declare an object or a class that is forced to have a int value between those numbers to use throughout my project, not just a one-variable use thing so an array isn't what I want here